# Is it possible add cash during the calculation of a strategy? (backtesting strategies for DCA)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I would like to add cash on a monthly basis. 'initial_capital' can only be static, it's not possible to put in a variable unfortunately.

I know I can track the investment with own variables, but I think there must be some way to calculate your overall investment without setting the initial capital to 1M and just take money off that.

I've posted this question on Reddit but no solution so far. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot modify your equity directly.

The workaround would be, as you suggested, set your initial capital to something very high but limit the amount you use in your trades. Then you can increase your limit each month.